# building rxjs pipe sequence that calls second http service to add additional data to model

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Problem**:
I am new to RXJS and having a hard time changing a pipe that is fetching http data and saving it in store conditionally (if status is active).
One of the properties of missing and I need to consume another http service on a item-by-item basis, to fetch that missing property before saving in store.
No need to call the second http service on items that have active=false flag.

**Example**:

The 2 methods that fetch http data:

```
FetchHttpData1() : Observable<IMainModelType[]>

FetchHttpItemProperty(id:number) : Observable<IMissingPropertyType>
```

models:

```
interface IMainModelType {
  id:number,
  name:string,
  missingProperty:string, //always null
  active:boolean
}

interface IMissingPropertyType{
  id:number,
  missingProperty:string
}
```

code so far:

```
let myObs = this.FetchHttpData1().pipe(
  map((values) => { 
    values.forEach((singleValue) => {

      if(singleValue.active) {
        //this singleValue is being saved with a missing property and we dont want that
        //at this stage I need to response from FetchHttpItemProperty() to try and set the missing property
        this.storeSetSingle(singleValue);
      }
      
    });
  })
);
```

Suggestions on how to add extra steps to call this.FetchHttpItemProperty(id) and make sure the item set in this.storeSetSingle() has the missing property defined?

I know this is probably very basic, but Im struggling with this for a while now and your suggestions will be opportunities to learn. Also open to suggestions if you think the current pipe could be better built.

Answer (score 6):

```
const missingApi$ = (x: IMainModelType) => this.FetchHttpItemProperty(x.id).pipe(
  map(({ missingProperty }) => ({...x, missingProperty})),
  tap((val) => this.storeSetSingle(val)),
);

let myObs = this.FetchHttpData1().pipe(switchMap((arrs) => 
  forkJoin(arrs.map((x) => x.active ? missingApi$(x) : of(x)))
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
let myObs = this.FetchHttpData1().pipe(
      switchMap((values: {id: number}[]) => {
          forkJoin(values.map(v => FetchHttpItemProperty(v.id))).pipe(
              map(vals => {
                  const results = values.map(val => {...val, ...vals.find(i => i.id === val.id)})
                  return results;
              }),
              tap(vals => vals.forEach(v => this.storeSetSingle(v)))
          )
      })
```

I'm just mentioning that is not a best practice to make an HTTP request inside looping an array, but if you don't have any control on the backend so here you go

good luck :)